# how to use persian JDF date class?

Tags: java, android, datetime, format, jalali-calendar

I found a class for convert Gregorian date to Jalali date

JDF.java

```
public class JDF {

    /**
     * Main: The default constructor uses the current Gregorian date to
     * initialize the other private memebers of the class (Iranian and Julian
     * dates).
     */
    public JDF() {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        setGregorianDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    public JDF(GregorianCalendar calendar) {
        setGregorianDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    public JDF(Calendar calendar) {
        setGregorianDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    /**
     * Main: This constructor receives a Gregorian date and initializes the
     * other private members of the class accordingly.
     *
     * @param year  int
     * @param month int
     * @param day   int
     * @return
     */
    public JDF(int year, int month, int day) {
        setGregorianDate(year, month, day);
    }

    /**
     * getIranianYear: Returns the 'year' part of the Iranian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getIranianYear() {
        return irYear;
    }

    /**
     * getIranianMonth: Returns the 'month' part of the Iranian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getIranianMonth() {
        return irMonth;
    }

    /**
     * getGregorianCalendar: gets Iranian date and returns Gregorian calendar
     *
     * @return calendar
     */
    public GregorianCalendar getGregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int day)
            throws ParseException {

        setIranianDate(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/M/d",
                Locale.US);
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(getGregorianDate());
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        return calendar;
    }

    /**
     * getIranianDayName: Returns the number of Iranian day of week
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getIranianDay(int year, int month, int day)
            throws ParseException {

        setIranianDate(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/M/d",
                Locale.US);
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(getGregorianDate());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(myDate);

        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 0;
        } else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 1;
        } else if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 2;
        } else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 3;
        } else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 4;
        } else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 5;
        } else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) {
            dayOfWeek = 6;
        }

        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    /**
     * getIranianDay: Returns the 'day' part of the Iranian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getIranianDay() {
        return irDay;
    }

    /**
     * getGregorianYear: Returns the 'year' part of the Gregorian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getGregorianYear() {
        return gYear;
    }

    /**
     * getGregorianMonth: Returns the 'month' part of the Gregorian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getGregorianMonth() {
        return gMonth;
    }

    /**
     * getGregorianDay: Returns the 'day' part of the Gregorian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getGregorianDay() {
        return gDay;
    }

    /**
     * getJulianYear: Returns the 'year' part of the Julian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getJulianYear() {
        return juYear;
    }

    /**
     * getJulianMonth: Returns the 'month' part of the Julian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getJulianMonth() {
        return juMonth;
    }

    /**
     * getJulianDay() Returns the 'day' part of the Julian date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getJulianDay() {
        return juDay;
    }

    /**
     * getIranianDate: Returns a string version of Iranian date
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getIranianDate() {
        return (irYear + "/" + irMonth + "/" + irDay);
    }

    /**
     * getGregorianDate: Returns a string version of Gregorian date
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getGregorianDate() {
        return (gYear + "/" + gMonth + "/" + gDay);
    }

    /**
     * getJulianDate: Returns a string version of Julian date
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getJulianDate() {
        return (juYear + "/" + juMonth + "/" + juDay);
    }

    /**
     * getWeekDayStr: Returns the week day name.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String getWeekDayStr() {
        String weekDayStr[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        return (weekDayStr[getDayOfWeek()]);
    }

    /**
     * toString: Overrides the default toString() method to return all dates.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (getWeekDayStr() + ", Gregorian:[" + getGregorianDate()
                + "], Julian:[" + getJulianDate() + "], Iranian:["
                + getIranianDate() + "]");
    }

    /**
     * getDayOfWeek: Returns the week day number. Monday=0..Sunday=6;
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public int getDayOfWeek() {
        return (JDN % 7);
    }

    /**
     * nextDay: Go to next julian day number (JDN) and adjusts the other dates.
     */
    public void nextDay() {
        JDN++;
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * nextDay: Overload the nextDay() method to accept the number of days to go
     * ahead and adjusts the other dates accordingly.
     *
     * @param days int
     */
    public void nextDay(int days) {
        JDN += days;
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * previousDay: Go to previous julian day number (JDN) and adjusts the otehr
     * dates.
     */
    public void previousDay() {
        JDN--;
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * previousDay: Overload the previousDay() method to accept the number of
     * days to go backward and adjusts the other dates accordingly.
     *
     * @param days int
     */
    public void previousDay(int days) {
        JDN -= days;
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * setIranianDate: Sets the date according to the Iranian calendar and
     * adjusts the other dates.
     *
     * @param year  int
     * @param month int
     * @param day   int
     */
    public void setIranianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        irYear = year;
        irMonth = month;
        irDay = day;
        JDN = IranianDateToJDN();
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * setGregorianDate: Sets the date according to the Gregorian calendar and
     * adjusts the other dates.
     *
     * @param year  int
     * @param month int
     * @param day   int
     */
    public void setGregorianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        gYear = year;
        gMonth = month;
        gDay = day;
        JDN = gregorianDateToJDN(year, month, day);
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * setJulianDate: Sets the date according to the Julian calendar and adjusts
     * the other dates.
     *
     * @param year  int
     * @param month int
     * @param day   int
     */
    public void setJulianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        juYear = year;
        juMonth = month;
        juDay = day;
        JDN = julianDateToJDN(year, month, day);
        JDNToIranian();
        JDNToJulian();
        JDNToGregorian();
    }

    /**
     * IranianCalendar: This method determines if the Iranian (Jalali) year is
     * leap (366-day long) or is the common year (365 days), and finds the day
     * in March (Gregorian Calendar)of the first day of the Iranian year
     * ('irYear').Iranian year (irYear) ranges from (-61 to 3177).This method
     * will set the following private data members as follows: leap: Number of
     * years since the last leap year (0 to 4) Gy: Gregorian year of the
     * begining of Iranian year march: The March day of Farvardin the 1st (first
     * day of jaYear)
     */
    private void IranianCalendar() {
        // Iranian years starting the 33-year rule
        int Breaks[] = {-61, 9, 38, 199, 426, 686, 756, 818, 1111, 1181, 1210,
                1635, 2060, 2097, 2192, 2262, 2324, 2394, 2456, 3178};
        int jm, N, leapJ, leapG, jp, j, jump;
        gYear = irYear + 621;
        leapJ = -14;
        jp = Breaks[0];
        // Find the limiting years for the Iranian year 'irYear'
        j = 1;
        do {
            jm = Breaks[j];
            jump = jm - jp;
            if (irYear >= jm) {
                leapJ += (jump / 33 * 8 + (jump % 33) / 4);
                jp = jm;
            }
            j++;
        } while ((j < 20) && (irYear >= jm));
        N = irYear - jp;
        // Find the number of leap years from AD 621 to the begining of the
        // current
        // Iranian year in the Iranian (Jalali) calendar
        leapJ += (N / 33 * 8 + ((N % 33) + 3) / 4);
        if (((jump % 33) == 4) && ((jump - N) == 4))
            leapJ++;
        // And the same in the Gregorian date of Farvardin the first
        leapG = gYear / 4 - ((gYear / 100 + 1) * 3 / 4) - 150;
        march = 20 + leapJ - leapG;
        // Find how many years have passed since the last leap year
        if ((jump - N) < 6)
            N = N - jump + ((jump + 4) / 33 * 33);
        leap = (((N + 1) % 33) - 1) % 4;
        if (leap == -1)
            leap = 4;
    }

    /**
     * IranianDateToJDN: Converts a date of the Iranian calendar to the Julian
     * Day Number. It first invokes the 'IranianCalender' private method to
     * convert the Iranian date to Gregorian date and then returns the Julian
     * Day Number based on the Gregorian date. The Iranian date is obtained from
     * 'irYear'(1-3100),'irMonth'(1-12) and 'irDay'(1-29/31).
     *
     * @return long (Julian Day Number)
     */
    private int IranianDateToJDN() {
        IranianCalendar();
        return (gregorianDateToJDN(gYear, 3, march) + (irMonth - 1) * 31
                - irMonth / 7 * (irMonth - 7) + irDay - 1);
    }

    /**
     * JDNToIranian: Converts the current value of 'JDN' Julian Day Number to a
     * date in the Iranian calendar. The caller should make sure that the
     * current value of 'JDN' is set correctly. This method first converts the
     * JDN to Gregorian calendar and then to Iranian calendar.
     */
    private void JDNToIranian() {
        JDNToGregorian();
        irYear = gYear - 621;
        IranianCalendar(); // This invocation will update 'leap' and 'march'
        int JDN1F = gregorianDateToJDN(gYear, 3, march);
        int k = JDN - JDN1F;
        if (k >= 0) {
            if (k <= 185) {
                irMonth = 1 + k / 31;
                irDay = (k % 31) + 1;
                return;
            } else
                k -= 186;
        } else {
            irYear--;
            k += 179;
            if (leap == 1)
                k++;
        }
        irMonth = 7 + k / 30;
        irDay = (k % 30) + 1;
    }

    /**
     * julianDateToJDN: Calculates the julian day number (JDN) from Julian
     * calendar dates. This integer number corresponds to the noon of the date
     * (i.e. 12 hours of Universal Time). This method was tested to be good
     * (valid) since 1 March, -100100 (of both calendars) up to a few millions
     * (10^6) years into the future. The algorithm is based on D.A.Hatcher,
     * Q.Jl.R.Astron.Soc. 25(1984), 53-55 slightly modified by K.M. Borkowski,
     * Post.Astron. 25(1987), 275-279.
     *
     * @param year  int
     * @param month int
     * @param day   int
     * @return int
     */
    private int julianDateToJDN(int year, int month, int day) {
        return (year + (month - 8) / 6 + 100100) * 1461 / 4
                + (153 * ((month + 9) % 12) + 2) / 5 + day - 34840408;
    }

    /**
     * JDNToJulian: Calculates Julian calendar dates from the julian day number
     * (JDN) for the period since JDN=-34839655 (i.e. the year -100100 of both
     * calendars) to some millions (10^6) years ahead of the present. The
     * algorithm is based on D.A. Hatcher, Q.Jl.R.Astron.Soc. 25(1984), 53-55
     * slightly modified by K.M. Borkowski, Post.Astron. 25(1987), 275-279).
     */
    private void JDNToJulian() {
        int j = 4 * JDN + 139361631;
        int i = ((j % 1461) / 4) * 5 + 308;
        juDay = (i % 153) / 5 + 1;
        juMonth = ((i / 153) % 12) + 1;
        juYear = j / 1461 - 100100 + (8 - juMonth) / 6;
    }

    /**
     * gergorianDateToJDN: Calculates the julian day number (JDN) from Gregorian
     * calendar dates. This integer number corresponds to the noon of the date
     * (i.e. 12 hours of Universal Time). This method was tested to be good
     * (valid) since 1 March, -100100 (of both calendars) up to a few millions
     * (10^6) years into the future. The algorithm is based on D.A.Hatcher,
     * Q.Jl.R.Astron.Soc. 25(1984), 53-55 slightly modified by K.M. Borkowski,
     * Post.Astron. 25(1987), 275-279.
     *
     * @param year  int
     * @param month int
     * @param day   int
     * @return int
     */
    private int gregorianDateToJDN(int year, int month, int day) {
        int jdn = (year + (month - 8) / 6 + 100100) * 1461 / 4
                + (153 * ((month + 9) % 12) + 2) / 5 + day - 34840408;
        jdn = jdn - (year + 100100 + (month - 8) / 6) / 100 * 3 / 4 + 752;
        return (jdn);
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        double a = 0.025;
        int b = 266;
        double leapDays0;
        double leapDays1;
        if (year > 0) {
            leapDays0 = ((year + 38) % 2820) * 0.24219 + a;
            leapDays1 = ((year + 39) % 2820) * 0.24219 + a;
        } else if (year < 0) {
            leapDays0 = ((year + 39) % 2820) * 0.24219 + a;
            leapDays1 = ((year + 40) % 2820) * 0.24219 + a;
        } else
            return false;

        int frac0 = (int) ((leapDays0 - (int) (leapDays0)) * 1000);
        int frac1 = (int) ((leapDays1 - (int) (leapDays1)) * 1000);

        return frac0 <= b && frac1 > b;
    }

    /**
     * JDNToGregorian: Calculates Gregorian calendar dates from the julian day
     * number (JDN) for the period since JDN=-34839655 (i.e. the year -100100 of
     * both calendars) to some millions (10^6) years ahead of the present. The
     * algorithm is based on D.A. Hatcher, Q.Jl.R.Astron.Soc. 25(1984), 53-55
     * slightly modified by K.M. Borkowski, Post.Astron. 25(1987), 275-279).
     */
    private void JDNToGregorian() {
        int j = 4 * JDN + 139361631;
        j = j + (((((4 * JDN + 183187720) / 146097) * 3) / 4) * 4 - 3908);
        int i = ((j % 1461) / 4) * 5 + 308;
        gDay = (i % 153) / 5 + 1;
        gMonth = ((i / 153) % 12) + 1;
        gYear = j / 1461 - 100100 + (8 - gMonth) / 6;
    }

    private int irYear; // Year part of a Iranian date
    private int irMonth; // Month part of a Iranian date
    private int irDay; // Day part of a Iranian date
    private int gYear; // Year part of a Gregorian date
    private int gMonth; // Month part of a Gregorian date
    private int gDay; // Day part of a Gregorian date
    private int juYear; // Year part of a Julian date
    private int juMonth; // Month part of a Julian date
    private int juDay; // Day part of a Julian date
    private int leap; // Number of years since the last leap year (0 to 4)
    private int JDN; // Julian Day Number
    private int march; // The march day of Farvardin the first (First day of
    // jaYear)
}
```

But i can't use this class for example i want to show jalali String date Like : پنجشنبه، ۱۴ تیر ۱۳۹۷

Unfortunately, the source site has not been fully explained , If somebody has been instructed about this class on Persian sites, please submit the site link

Comment: That’s right, I don’t see any formatting capabilities in the code you have posted. You may be able to find that somewhere else. If not, it seems you will have to build it from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library:

> com.mohamadamin.persianmaterialdatetimepicker.utils

```
    /**
 * Persian Calendar see: http://code.google.com/p/persian-calendar/
   Copyright (C) 2012  Mortezaadi@gmail.com
   PersianCalendar.java

   Persian Calendar is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
package com.mohamadamin.persianmaterialdatetimepicker.utils;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * 
 * <strong> Persian(Shamsi) calendar </strong>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The calendar consists of 12 months, the first six of which are 31 days, the
 * next five 30 days, and the final month 29 days in a normal year and 30 days
 * in a leap year.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * As one of the few calendars designed in the era of accurate positional
 * astronomy, the Persian calendar uses a very complex leap year structure which
 * makes it the most accurate solar calendar in use today. Years are grouped
 * into cycles which begin with four normal years after which every fourth
 * subsequent year in the cycle is a leap year. Cycles are grouped into grand
 * cycles of either 128 years (composed of cycles of 29, 33, 33, and 33 years)
 * or 132 years, containing cycles of of 29, 33, 33, and 37 years. A great grand
 * cycle is composed of 21 consecutive 128 year grand cycles and a final 132
 * grand cycle, for a total of 2820 years. The pattern of normal and leap years
 * which began in 1925 will not repeat until the year 4745!
 * </p>
 * </p> Each 2820 year great grand cycle contains 2137 normal years of 365 days
 * and 683 leap years of 366 days, with the average year length over the great
 * grand cycle of 365.24219852. So close is this to the actual solar tropical
 * year of 365.24219878 days that the Persian calendar accumulates an error of
 * one day only every 3.8 million years. As a purely solar calendar, months are
 * not synchronized with the phases of the Moon. </p>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * 
 * <p>
 * <strong>PersianCalendar</strong> by extending Default GregorianCalendar
 * provides capabilities such as:
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * 
 * <li>you can set the date in Persian by setPersianDate(persianYear,
 * persianMonth, persianDay) and get the Gregorian date or vice versa</li>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <li>determine is the current date is Leap year in persian calendar or not by
 * IsPersianLeapYear()</li>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <li>getPersian short and long Date String getPersianShortDate() and
 * getPersianLongDate you also can set delimiter to assign delimiter of returned
 * dateString</li>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <li>Parse string based on assigned delimiter</li>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * <strong> Example </strong>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *       PersianCalendar persianCal = new PersianCalendar();
 *       System.out.println(persianCal.getPersianShortDate());
 *       
 *       persianCal.set(1982, Calendar.MAY, 22);
 *       System.out.println(persianCal.getPersianShortDate());
 *       
 *       persianCal.setDelimiter(" , ");
 *       persianCal.parse("1361 , 03 , 01");
 *       System.out.println(persianCal.getPersianShortDate());
 *       
 *       persianCal.setPersianDate(1361, 3, 1);
 *       System.out.println(persianCal.getPersianLongDate());
 *       System.out.println(persianCal.getTime());
 *       
 *       persianCal.addPersianDate(Calendar.MONTH, 33);
 *       persianCal.addPersianDate(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
 *       persianCal.addPersianDate(Calendar.DATE, 50);
 * 
 * }
 * 
 * <pre>
 * @author Morteza  contact: <a href="mailto:Mortezaadi@gmail.com">Mortezaadi@gmail.com</a>
 * @version 1.1
 */
public class PersianCalendar extends GregorianCalendar {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5541422440580682494L;

    private int persianYear;
    private int persianMonth;
    private int persianDay;
    // use to seperate PersianDate's field and also Parse the DateString based
    // on this delimiter
    private String delimiter = "/";

    private long convertToMilis(long julianDate) {
        return PersianCalendarConstants.MILLIS_JULIAN_EPOCH + julianDate * PersianCalendarConstants.MILLIS_OF_A_DAY
                + PersianCalendarUtils.ceil(getTimeInMillis() - PersianCalendarConstants.MILLIS_JULIAN_EPOCH, PersianCalendarConstants.MILLIS_OF_A_DAY);
    }

    /**
     * default constructor
     * 
     * most of the time we don't care about TimeZone when we persisting Date or
     * doing some calculation on date. <strong> Default TimeZone was set to
     * "GMT" </strong> in order to make developer to work more convenient with
     * the library; however you can change the TimeZone as you do in
     * GregorianCalendar by calling setTimeZone()
     */
    public PersianCalendar(long millis) {
        setTimeInMillis(millis);
    }

    /**
     * default constructor
     * 
     * most of the time we don't care about TimeZone when we persisting Date or
     * doing some calculation on date. <strong> Default TimeZone was set to
     * "GMT" </strong> in order to make developer to work more convenient with
     * the library; however you can change the TimeZone as you do in
     * GregorianCalendar by calling setTimeZone()
     */
    public PersianCalendar() {
        setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    /**
     * Calculate persian date from current Date and populates the corresponding
     * fields(persianYear, persianMonth, persianDay)
     */
    protected void calculatePersianDate() {
        long julianDate = ((long) Math.floor((getTimeInMillis() - PersianCalendarConstants.MILLIS_JULIAN_EPOCH)) / PersianCalendarConstants.MILLIS_OF_A_DAY);
        long PersianRowDate = PersianCalendarUtils.julianToPersian(julianDate);
        long year = PersianRowDate >> 16;
        int month = (int) (PersianRowDate & 0xff00) >> 8;
        int day = (int) (PersianRowDate & 0xff);
        this.persianYear = (int) (year > 0 ? year : year - 1);
        this.persianMonth = month;
        this.persianDay = day;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Determines if the given year is a leap year in persian calendar. Returns
     * true if the given year is a leap year.
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isPersianLeapYear() {
        // calculatePersianDate();
        return PersianCalendarUtils.isPersianLeapYear(this.persianYear);
    }

    /**
     * set the persian date it converts PersianDate to the Julian and assigned
     * equivalent milliseconds to the instance
     * 
     * @param persianYear
     * @param persianMonth
     * @param persianDay
     */
    public void setPersianDate(int persianYear, int persianMonth, int persianDay) {
        persianMonth += 1; // TODO
        this.persianYear = persianYear;
        this.persianMonth = persianMonth;
        this.persianDay = persianDay;
        setTimeInMillis(convertToMilis(PersianCalendarUtils.persianToJulian(this.persianYear > 0 ? this.persianYear : this.persianYear + 1, this.persianMonth - 1, this.persianDay)));
    }

    public int getPersianYear() {
        // calculatePersianDate();
        return this.persianYear;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return int persian month number
     */
    public int getPersianMonth() {
        // calculatePersianDate();
        return this.persianMonth;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return String persian month name
     */
    public String getPersianMonthName() {
        // calculatePersianDate();
        return PersianCalendarConstants.persianMonthNames[this.persianMonth];
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return int Persian day in month
     */
    public int getPersianDay() {
        // calculatePersianDate();
        return this.persianDay;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return String Name of the day in week
     */
    public String getPersianWeekDayName() {
        switch (get(DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        case SATURDAY:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[0];
        case SUNDAY:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[1];
        case MONDAY:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[2];
        case TUESDAY:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[3];
        case WEDNESDAY:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[4];
        case THURSDAY:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[5];
        default:
            return PersianCalendarConstants.persianWeekDays[6];
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return String of Persian Date ex: شنبه 01 خرداد 1361
     */
    public String getPersianLongDate() {
        return getPersianWeekDayName() + "  " + this.persianDay + "  " + getPersianMonthName() + "  " + this.persianYear;
    }

    public String getPersianLongDateAndTime() {
        return getPersianLongDate() + " ساعت " + get(HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + get(MINUTE) + ":" + get(SECOND);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return String of persian date formatted by
     *         'YYYY[delimiter]mm[delimiter]dd' default delimiter is '/'
     */
    public String getPersianShortDate() {
        // calculatePersianDate();
        return "" + formatToMilitary(this.persianYear) + delimiter + formatToMilitary(getPersianMonth()+1) + delimiter + formatToMilitary(this.persianDay);
    }

    public String getPersianShortDateTime() {
        return "" + formatToMilitary(this.persianYear) + delimiter + formatToMilitary(getPersianMonth()+1) + delimiter + formatToMilitary(this.persianDay) + " " + formatToMilitary(this.get(HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + formatToMilitary(get(MINUTE))
                + ":" + formatToMilitary(get(SECOND));
    }

    private String formatToMilitary(int i) {
        return (i < 9) ? "0" + i : String.valueOf(i);
    }

    /**
     * add specific amout of fields to the current date for now doesnt handle
     * before 1 farvardin hejri (before epoch)
     * 
     * @param field
     * @param amount
     *            <pre>
     *  Usage:
     *  {@code
     *  addPersianDate(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
     *  addPersianDate(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
     *  }
     * </pre>
     * 
     *            u can also use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Calendar.MINUTE,
     *            Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND etc
     */
    //
    public void addPersianDate(int field, int amount) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            return; // Do nothing!
        }

        if (field < 0 || field >= ZONE_OFFSET) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (field == YEAR) {
            setPersianDate(this.persianYear + amount, getPersianMonth()+1, this.persianDay);
            return;
        } else if (field == MONTH) {
            setPersianDate(this.persianYear + ((getPersianMonth()+1 + amount) / 12), (getPersianMonth()+1 + amount) % 12, this.persianDay);
            return;
        }
        add(field, amount);
        calculatePersianDate();
    }

    /**
     * <pre>
     *    use <code>{@link PersianDateParser}</code> to parse string 
     *    and get the Persian Date.
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @see PersianDateParser
     * @param dateString
     */
    public void parse(String dateString) {
        PersianCalendar p = new PersianDateParser(dateString, delimiter).getPersianDate();
        setPersianDate(p.getPersianYear(), p.getPersianMonth(), p.getPersianDay());
    }

    public String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    /**
     * assign delimiter to use as a separator of date fields.
     * 
     * @param delimiter
     */
    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = super.toString();
        return str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + ",PersianDate=" + getPersianShortDate() + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int field, int value) {
        super.set(field, value);
        calculatePersianDate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTimeInMillis(long millis) {
        super.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        calculatePersianDate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTimeZone(TimeZone zone) {
        super.setTimeZone(zone);
        calculatePersianDate();
    }

}
```

and if you want exact format you said you can use something like this:

```
        PersianCalendar pers = new PersianCalendar();
        String.format(
                    Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%s %d %d:%d",
                    pers.getPersianMonthName(),
                    pers.getPersianDay(),
                    pers.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    pers.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

your JDF Class have the bug.

you can use JDF Class from way search in google.
and for use of JDF Class standard :

```
String string = "Sun, 21 Jul 2019 00:27:28";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

Date date = null;
try {
    date = format.parse(string);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    JDF jdf = new JDF(calendar);
    String time = jdf.getIranianDate() + " " 
    + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" +calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```